# Chrome Extension removing Listener doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building my first Chrome extension and this is a problem I'm struggling with for days now.

When extension is on, it adds a listener and blocks requests, but when it's off, it should remove the listener (not block the requests). Problem is, the removeListener doesn't work for some reason.

```
  chrome.storage.local.get(["button"], function(result) {
    //
    let extensionState = result.button;
    let blocksRequestsFunction = function(details) {
      if (extensionState === "on") {
        console.log("blocking:", details.url);
        return { cancel: true };
      } else {
        console.log("it's off");

        chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.removeListener(
          blocksRequestsFunction
        );
        return { cancel: true };
      }
    };

    function blocksAds() {
      chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        blocksRequestsFunction,
        { urls: ["*://*.adjaranet.com/"] },
        ["blocking"]
      );
    }

    blocksAds();
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to make that function reference global as I explained already. Move `let blocksRequestsFunction` statement outside of any functions e.g. make it the first statement in your script.

Comment: you return return { cancel: true }; in both if and else blocks maybe you should return false.

Comment: I moved the function but in the function, I have another variable "extensionState".